# What's the hadith where a pious man tells sinful man he's going to hell and both of their deeds are reduced to none?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I remember a hadith that talks about how a pious man claimed that the sinful man can't be forgiven, i.e. definitely going to hell, and a voice said his sins and your good deeds have both been erased start over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> أن رجلا قال والله لا يغفر الله لفلان وإن الله تعالى قال من ذا الذي يتألى على أن لا أغفر لفلان فإني قد غفرت لفلان وأحبطت عملك
>
> A man said: 'By Allah, Allah will not forgive so-and-so.' Allah said: 'Who is the one who swore by Me that I will not forgive so-and-so? I have forgiven so-and-so and I have cancelled out your good deeds.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim 2621](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2621)</sup>